# Arduino MKRZero "This device cannot start" (Code 10), and Keyboard.h

Tags: serial, hardware, keyboard, mkrzero

I have bought my brand new Arduino MKRZero to emulate a keyboard. When I plug it in, I get the following on COM6, which is listed as "Arduino MKRZero".

"This device cannot start" (Code 10)

[image: ![image|402x450](upload://2ys9cT0qBD8jgMtzldUfvHLboId.png)]

I also get a new COM port connection, COM3, listed as a generic USB Serial Device.

[image: ![image|389x137](upload://iZGu03re8ovSh80b2EhwCuqzNLE.png)]

In my IDE (2.1.0) I am given the following:

[image: ![image|419x478](upload://qpDwaiL6GOMFx2Bonl6pgFVCp4Z.png)]

COM 3 opens on the Serial Monitor, while COM 6 gives a port monitor error:

[image: ![image|690x149](upload://rRsTPxCwVEv3BINi2234Dpn4wAf.png)]

### Attempts

I have tried a few things based on the following:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/solved-arduino-uno-this-device-cannot-start-code-10-at-hardware-manager/298777
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/this-device-cannot-start-code-10-arduino-leonardo/897137
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-10-errors-2623181

- Updating drivers
- Rolling back drivers
- Using a different USB connector
- Restarting laptop

### Context

The reason why I ask is because I am attempting to use the following code in an Arduino, which, per my understanding, should print the letter "F" every second with my keyboard.

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  // open the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize control over the keyboard:
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
    Keyboard.write('F');
    delay(1000);
}
```

However, no response is received.

Please let me know if more information is required, or if this is a code issue. I am on Win 10.0.19045, and attempted both the latest version and an alleged, more stable version of the MKRZero driver (Arduino SAMD Boards [32-bits ARM Cortex-M0+] version 1.8.13 and 1.8.9).

Comment: if you upload Blink or some other sketch without Keyboard library, everything is normal? one com port? which one?